# References on integration on non-compact manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, integration, smooth-manifolds, manifolds

I am looking for references on integration on non-compact Riemannian manifolds, specially on the change of variables theorem.

In particular I have non-compact manifold $M$ and I have an integral (in most interesting cases for me improper integral)

$$\int_M f(x) \mu(dx)$$

Where $\mu$ is standard volume measure on $M$ generated by the metric tensor $g$ on $M$. And I need to make change of variables $y=\phi (x)$, where $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism $\phi: M \to M$. Function $f$ may be unbounded, manifold $M$ may be unbounded (say $M= \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}^2$).

I have found reference book only for compact manifolds and bounded functions.

Please help with reference applicable to my case. Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you be more specific? The standard change of variables formula is a local one and therefore valid on any manifold without boundary.

Comment: Nearly all results for integration on compact manifolds can be transferred to noncompact via partitions of unity.

Comment: thank you both!

Comment: @NateEldredge which aspects could not be transferred?! a reference would highly be appreciated.